# How to handle different exception http types with try-catch in Java?

Tags: java, rest, http, exception, try-catch

I am a beginner in API with Java, I am writing the RESTful APIs, and now I need to write the API Handler to handle the request from the front-end. Just noticed there are so many kinds of HTTP error when handling the request.

So I am wondering how to catch these exceptions with `try-catch` in Java.

I did one very basic `try-catch` to handle the `InvalidRequestException`, which refers to the exception from the client side.

```
    @Override
    public String handle(final APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent event) {
        if (event.getHttpMethod().equalsIgnoreCase(HttpMethod.POST.name())) {
            try{
                FeatureRecord featureRecord = Jackson.fromJsonString(event.getBody(), FeatureRecord.class);
                featureProcessor.createFeature(featureRecord);
                return EMPTY_STRING;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new InvalidRequestException(ex);
            }
        }
```

Now I want to split the exception type to distinguish different HTTP exceptions, like this:

```
    @Override
    public String handle(final APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent event) {
        if (event.getHttpMethod().equalsIgnoreCase(HttpMethod.POST.name())) {
            try{
                FeatureRecord featureRecord = Jackson.fromJsonString(event.getBody(), FeatureRecord.class);
                featureProcessor.createFeature(featureRecord);
                return EMPTY_STRING;
            } catch (InvalidRequestException ex) {
                throw new InvalidRequestException(ex);
            } catch (ServiceInternalException ex) {
                throw new ServiceInternalException(ex);
            } ... ...
        }
```

But I don't know how to write the `catch` sections.

I know there are many exception types from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500, but how to handle them with `try-catch`? Do I need to write the new Exception type?

Comment: You shouldn't just catch and throw the same exception. If that's all you do, don't catch it, there is no point in just adding it as a cause for a new exception. The question is: what do you want to do when the request is invalid? What do you want to do when the service has an internal failure? Once you know that, you can write the `catch` code properly.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what you're asking here. You use `try`/`catch` to *catch* exceptions raised by code you write within the `try` block. Does that code really raise these exceptions? It doesn't look like [`getBody`](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/blob/master/aws-lambda-java-events/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/events/APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent.java#L1096) does, for instance, and I can't imagine why Jackson would raise exceptions like that reading a *string*.

Answer (score 0):

### Catching more exception types

You can `catch` several exception types with a single `catch` if you catch their common ancestor `class`. For example

```
try {
    //some code
} catch (Exception ex) {
    //handling the catch
}
```

will catch all exceptions, so please be as general as possible, but still handle the errors properly, so catching `Exception` might be or might not be an option for you, depending on your situation.

### Ways to handle an exception

You are catching several exception types and instead of handling them or throwing them, you `throw` an exception of the same type. For instance there is no reason to do this:

```
try {
    //some code
} catch (InvalidRequestException ex) {
    throw new InvalidRequestException(ex);
}
```

instead of this:

```
try {
    //some code
} catch (InvalidRequestException ex) {
    throw ex;
}
```

But if your `catch` is *only* throwing the same exception, then there is no point having the `catch` at all. You would need to make the errors user-friendly, that is, send a response to the user explaining the problems and then `throw` the exception. Or, you can avoid throwing the exception at all inside the `catch` and log some message instead.

### Implementing your own Exception

This is of course an option and could be feasible if you have some custom error types.